# Mapping data from JSON sourced from Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

As I'm new to React, I have been struggling with mapping JSON data for a couple days now. What I have below is my App.js file. I am trying to map the data pulled from an external JSON into my array labelled `airData` and then into the Components further down the page. The data correctly prints to the console but the array seems empty when I try and actually use and map the data. Any direction is appreciated.

My App.js:

```
const airData = []

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      airData: []
    }
   }

componentDidMount(){

  var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxx");

      var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
      urlencoded.append("macAddress", "xxxxxxxxxx");
      urlencoded.append("mode", "minute");

      var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
      };

  fetch("MY_API_URL", requestOptions)
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data => {
     console.log(data)
     this.setState({
       airData: data
     })
   });
  }


  
  render () {
        return (
          <div className="app">
            <Header />
            <div className="spacer"></div>
            <OverallStatus />
            {airData.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconHumidity} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Humidity {data.humidity}%</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.humidity}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconAirPressure} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Air Pressure {data.AirPressure} hPa</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.AirPressure}
                      maxCompleted={1030} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Dioxide {data.CO2} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO2}
                      maxCompleted={2000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconVOCs} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Chemicals {data.TVOC} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.TVOC}
                      maxCompleted={1000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconParticulateMatter} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Particles {data.PM25} ug/m3</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.PM25}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonMonoxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Monoxide {data.CO} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconNitrogenDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Nitrogen Dioxide {data.NO2} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.NO2}
                      maxCompleted={200} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconOzone} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Ozone {data.Ozone} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.Ozone}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
              );})}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
  
  

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of this:

```
const airData = []
```

You're storing "air data" in *state* correctly, and you never need or update that `const` that's outside the component.  *However*, you are referring to that `const` when rendering the component which is confusing you.

Get rid of the above `const` and render from the state value:

```
{this.state.airData.map(data => {
  ...
```

Comment: After doing so I now get the following error: TypeError: this.state.airData.map is not a function at App.render (App.js:75:1)

Comment: @MikeBarbaro: Double-check what you’re setting the state to. Because that error means it’s not an array, but the initial state is an empty array.

Comment: Thats where I get very confused because when I console log I get the JSON result as follows but can't get it to set State. `{"data":[{"virusIndex":4,"temperature":26,"humidity":63.9,"pm25":3,"tvoc":145,"co2":891,"co":0,"airPressure":992.2,"ozone":7.8,"no2":6.2,"timestamp":1646100155}],"usersettings":{"temperature":"°C","temp":"c","humidity":"%","pm25":"µg/m^3","dust":"µg/m^3","tvoc":"ppb","voc":"ppb","co2":"ppm","co":"ppm","airPressure":"mbar","pressure":"mbar","ozone":"ppb","no2":"ppb","pm1":"µg/m^3","pm4":"µg/m^3","pm10":"µg/m^3","ch2o":"ppb","light":"lux","sound":"dBA"},"count":29}`

Comment: @MikeBarbaro: That’s the problem right there.  What you’re logging to the console isn’t an array.  It’s an object with a property that is an array.  Don’t set the state to “data”, set it to “data.data” instead.  (Maybe rename the variable to something other than “data” to avoid the confusion.)

Comment: I was able to get the API to provide a new JSON response of `{data: Array(1), usersettings: {…}, count: 89}
count: 89
data: Array(1)
0:
airPressure: 991.3
co: 0
co2: 452
humidity: 58.3
no2: 16.5
ozone: 8.6
pm25: 6
temperature: 26.6
timestamp: 1646109034
tvoc: 243
virusIndex: 2` and tried `data.data` which got rid of the errors but doesn't display in my component. Again I thank you for your direction.

Comment: @MikeBarbaro: A lot of the properties in your component don't match what's in teh data you're showing.  For example, in the component you are looking for a property called `co2` but in what you're showing the property is called `CO2`.  The names need to match.

Answer (score 0):

You have airData and this.state.airData - two different things

In render function you iterate over airData which is empty.

```js
airData.map(data => {
```

Try to replace with

```js
this.state.airData.map(data => {
```

Comment: After doing so I now get the following error:  TypeError: this.state.airData.map is not a function at App.render (App.js:75:1)

Comment: Then check if it not undefined.